# % OFF WITH FIXED AMOUNT DISCOUNT (FLAT 10% Upto Rs 1000 only)

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make a rule where I offer my customers a discount of:

10% on a specific category, but the max discount amount is fixed to Rs 1000

Can I make this in Magento 1.9 or 2, using one or a couple of rules?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the standard Magento install. You need a module like Amasty Special Promotions that include this feature.